# JScrollPane on a TextArea

Tags: java, jframe

Okay, I've read almost all the threads about this topic in this website, but they all look confusing to me to be honest and none of them works with my code.
I've created a simple TextArea

```
JTextArea ttt=new JTextArea("");
ttt.setSize(500, 300);
ttt.setLocation(10, 100);
ttt.setEditable(false);
```

then created the Scrollpane with this line and added it to the TextArea

```
JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(ttt,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

And added it to my JFrame afterwards

```
myForm.add(sp);
```

As I read on most of the threads, this code should be working, but it's not. The TextArea was shown on the frame before I try to add the ScrollPane, but now the whole TextArea isn't even showing. Thank you.

Edit; here's my main for example, isn't working

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame myForm=new JFrame("Connect-4");
        myForm.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2)); // assign layout
        myForm.setSize(new Dimension(500,400)); // size

        JTextArea ttt = new JTextArea (3,3 );
        ttt.setEditable(false);
        //ttt.setSize(500, 300);
        //ttt.setLocation(10, 100);     
        JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(ttt,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        myForm.add(sp);

        myForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myForm.setLayout(null);
        myForm.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Edit 2; 2 Jlabel, 2 textfield, button and a textarea
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xRj3.jpg)

Edit 3;

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                JButton button=new JButton("Add");
        //button.setSize(100, 50);
        //button.setLocation(450, 40);


        JTextField tf1=new JTextField();
        tf1.setSize(150, 30);
        tf1.setLocation(70, 52);


        JLabel l1=new JLabel("Name");
        //l1.setSize(51, 50);
        //l1.setLocation(10, 40);
        l1.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));


        JTextField tf2=new JTextField();
        tf2.setSize(150, 30);
        tf2.setLocation(285, 52);

        JLabel l2=new JLabel("Phone");
        l2.setSize(55, 50);
        l2.setLocation(225, 40);
        l2.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        //////
        JTextArea ttt=new JTextArea("");
        ttt.setSize(500, 300);
        ttt.setLocation(10, 100);

        JPanel panel1=new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel1.add(l1);
        panel1.add(tf1);
        panel1.add(l2);
        panel1.add(tf2);    
        panel1.add(button);


        JPanel panel2=new JPanel();
        panel2.add(new JButton("FSFSD"));
        panel2.add(new JButton("RIGHT"));

        JPanel all=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        all.add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        all.add(ttt, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(all);
        //frame.add(all);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: The positions of the statements in your code is very important to ensure your GUI works fine. So detailed code about how you organize your code would help us to help you.

Comment: @YoungMillie Okay, added!

Comment: Get rid of the `myForm.setLayout(null);` toward the end of your `main` method.

Comment: @Thomas Its shown now, thanks. But how do I set its position liked I used to set the textarea position with .setposition, the current textarea is shown on top of the frame, I want to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a layout with

```
myForm.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2));
```

and then removing it with

```
myForm.setLayout(null);
```

Remove this line and you will see your text area.

You might also want to call `myFrame.pack()` before displaying the frame.

Comment: Alright its shown, but how do I set its position like I used to do with the textarea.setPosition() ?

Comment: @Ahmed The layout manager does it for you. Choose a layout manager that fits your GUI and it will take care of all positions. Don't assign positions manually.

Comment: @Ahmed Watch the language. The layout managers arrange components for you because setting components manually is bad. Your question doesn't say anything about positioning the text area and you are not showing us what the GUI should look like, so no one can help you at this point.

Comment: Sorry. I understand that I never mentioned anything about that because I didnt know I will use layout managers, its actually bad for me to set it automatically, simce I already set it manually and want it to look like that, should I post my code to tell me which or how layout I should use? Sorry for wasting youe time tho.

Comment: @Ahmed You should post a picture or ASCII art of what you want the GUI to look like.

Comment: Posted an img in the original post

Comment: @Ahmed Put the labels, text fields and button in a flow layout panel. Then add that panel to the top position in a border layout panel. Add the text area to the center of that border layout panel.

Comment: @Ahmed You are not using a `Borderlayout` container like i suggested and you are still setting size and location manually. I suggest you ask a new question about achieving your desired layout because your question was about the text area and that's it;

Comment: Actually, I just did it and updated my original post with what you said., the only thing I can't do is changing the textfield size since it's really small. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the TextArea follows

```
JTextArea ttt = new JTextArea (3,3 );
ttt.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane sp=new JScrollPane(ttt,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
myJFrame.add(sp);
```

> verify that your JFrame contains a suitable layaut and also the width
>   and height for example

```
myJFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2)); // assign layout
myJFrame.setSize(new Dimension(500,400)); // size
```

Comment: Still not working, I've added a code in my original post, if you can have a look